# Main Drawbacks of stepwise regression

Tags: statistical-significance, feature-selection, predictor

People typically prefer the Lasso or other methods to stepwise regression.

What are the main problems in stepwise regression which makes it unreliable
specifically the problems with forward selection , backward elimination and Bidirectional elimination?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/) for a nice list of issues and search the site as this has been discussed extensively.

One of the issues is that the remaining coefficients are biased and need shrinkage which is what the LASSO and its cousins (i.e. the elastic net, ridge regression) try to achieve.

Comment: The frequency with which this question occurs implies the answers on the thread cited are inadequate.