# Univariate analysis then multivariate analysis

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis

If I do univariate analyses to select variables that I will include in a multivariate analysis* [(I know this is not advised)](https://www.jclinepi.com/article/0895-4356(96)00025-X/fulltext), and for a given categorical variable, in the univariate analysis, category 0 has a p-value = 0.005 but category 2 has a p-value = 0.5 for example (reference category being category 1).

Should I include the categorical variable (category 0 and category 2, category 1 being the reference) as a whole or should I create a new categorical variable (category 0 = former category 0 and category 1 (reference) = category 1 or category 2).

Finally, as stated before, I know this is not advised, but are there things I can do to use this method (some sort of p value adjustment, some sort of correlation tests on the variables?)

(* it's a linear regression)

Comment: The logic of your question is "I'm doing stuff that's known to be wrong.  If I continue with it, can I fix up the problems?"  It answers itself.

Comment: It's not wrong when the different dependent variables aren't correlated / inversely correlated though (this has been verified in my dataset). It's only wrong because people forget to verify it. My question mainly has to do with how to treat categorical variables and also asks for references as to ways to better prove the validity of carrying out this method.

Comment: Btw, I'm far from being an expert so I might be wrong but this is what I've understood when reading the article.

Comment: If your question is about coding categorical variables, then why does it dwell on univariate *vs* multivariate analysis? That makes it difficult to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Actually, I think this question is exactly mine (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473051/question-regarding-selection-variables-for-a-multiple-logistic-regression-analys). I apologize for making a duplicate.

Comment: No problem -- you do us a service by finding the duplicate!

Comment: Should I delete the post or leave it that way?

Comment: It's your call.