# Interpretation of AIC, BIC and KIC

Tags: model-selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to prefer the AIC or BIC over the other?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-the-aic-or-bic-over-the-other)

Can anyone please interpret each term in AIC, BIC and KIC. And the difference between the three.

Thanks in advance,