# Cross-validation for mixed-effect logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, cross-validation

I would like to use cross-validation to test how predictive my mixed-effect logistic regression model is (model run with glmer). Is there an easy way to do this using a package in R? I've only seen cross validation functions in R for use with linear models.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for R packages / code.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user1566200. If you are only asking about how to do this in R, this is be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). R-based programming questions can be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but this isn't a programming question, & it lacks a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/), so it would be off-topic on SO as well. The r-help-listserv might be a viable option. If you have a question about the substantive statistical issues here, please edit to clarify, else this may be closed.

Comment: Sorry! Didn't realize R package questions aren't allowed here. Where can I repost?

Comment: @user1566200: no need to repost. If enough users agree that the question is more on-topic at SX, it will be migrated.

Comment: No need to apologize, it's an easy mistake. CV is a Q&A site for statistics (ML, data-viz., etc.) questions, not for how to use software. I would guess the best option would be the r-hlep-listserv, but it's not clear you will need to re-post. The answer for R is already given.

Comment: I'm no expert on mixed models, but for testing predictive performance you need to make sure that the splitting is done on the uppermost level of your data hierarchy. Otherwise you have a "leak" between training and test data.

Comment: Also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18971/cross-validation-for-mixed-models?rq=1 may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/) package. It has utilities to simplify building and comparing models based on really any arbitrary algorithm. The particular function in the package you are looking for is `train`.

[This page](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/training.html) gives a demo of how to fit a model using the `train` function with 10-fold cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't see glmer/Mixed Effects models as model options for train.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the `train` function, you'll see it directs you to the following instructions on using `train` with user defined (or otherwise unsupported) models: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/custom_models.html

Comment: Is it possible to tell `caret` that there is a grouping/clustering in the data that must be taken into account when splitting the data - but that otherwise the splitting should be random?

Comment: Check out their page on data splitting. http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/splitting.html

Comment: I know that page, and as far as I understand it there is no indication of splitting by a given grouping. However, I  thought you may have further insight (e.g. newly added functionality which is not yet explained on the web page).

Comment: If I understand what you're asking: set up your grouping as a class variable, and then pass that classification to `createDataPartition` as described on that page. Maybe I don't understand what you're asking, but I'm fairly certain that page holds your answer.