# BIC in Item Response Theory Models: Using log(N) vs log(N*I) as a weight

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, glmm, bic, item-response-theory

In IRT software packages and in the literature it is common to calculate the BIC as

$$
\mathrm{BIC} = -2 \cdot \mathrm{logLik} + \log(N)\mathrm{Npars}
$$

where $N$ is the number of rows in wide format (i.e. the number of persons) and $\mathrm{Npars}$ is the number of parameters. This is for example the way the R-packages `ltm` and `TAM` implement the BIC.

Typically IRT data is supplied in wide format, with one row per person and $I$ columns per item. If IRT data is reshaped to long format, it seems more natural to use $\log(N\cdot I)$ as a weight in the BIC criterion instead of $\log(N)$.

This is the perspective of generalized linear mixed models. In fact this is the output of the BIC method in `lme4` if `glmer` is used to fit the Rasch model, as for example DeBoeck et al. (2011) illustrate in their JSS article on the estimation of IRT Models with `glmer`.

Clearly it could make a difference which weight is chosen, as the difference in BIC values is multiplied/divided by the factor $\log(N\cdot I)/\log(N)$. Is there an authorative source or some kind of argument in favour of one of the weights?

Comment: this feels strongly related to the "level of focus" question with regard to conditional AIC, DIC, etc ... although AIC/DIC/etc. are [predictive rather than model distinction criteria](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-the-aic-or-bic-over-the-other)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's neither. The "textbook" information criteria formulation that you cite are derived for i.i.d. data, while you have a two-way array with weird cross-dependencies: you have the same questions, and you have the same students.

The issue is always there with mixed models. I am not going to try to reproduce their expressions, but Delattre et. al. (2014) paper ([DOI:10.1214/14-EJS890](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1399035845)) derives the relevant contributions from the observation-level (student-by-item) and cluster-level (student) data. They, however, seem to be oblivious to the prior work by the [SAMSI group on Bayesian latent variable modeling](https://www.samsi.info/programs/2004-05-program-latent-variable-models-social-sciences), although frankly it did not do such a great job of documenting their results. The most important one is fully documented only in [somebody's presentation](http://math.bu.edu/people/sray/talk/jsm_2007.pdf). It was quoted by Jim Berger in the [2007 Wald lecture at the Joint Statistical Meetings](https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring09/sta395/wald-2.pdf). Finally, a rather lean book on [random effect and latent variable model selection](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387767208) edited by David Dunson appear to have closely related results, but don't derive them in the form applicable to construction of the mixed-model BIC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these hints. I had merely skimmed through Dunson's volume, and thought it only relevant for nested models, but I will give it another try. The link labelled "somebody's presentation" is the same as the "SAMSI" one. Which presentation did you exactly refer to?

Comment: I fixed the link, see if it helps.