# Leave-One-Out-Cross-Validation error for least squares linear regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation

In LOOCV, in general, the model has to be fit n times (n being the number of observations). The test error is then estimated as a mean of all the individual test errors.

Hastie and Tibshirani mention in section 5.1.2 of their [book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf) that with least squares linear or polynomial regression, the cost of LOOCV reduces to that of a single model fit, given by

$CV_{(n)} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{y_i - \hat{y_i}}{1 - h_i})^2$

where $\hat{y_i}$ is the $i$th fitted value from the original least squares fit, and $h_i$ is the leverage statistic.

1. Could you please explain how this result can be proved?
2. Even after getting the estimate for the test error, how is the model chosen?

Comment: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164223/proof-of-loocv-formula/164277#164277