# How to prove the LOOCV formula for smoothing matrix?

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, cross-validation, smoothing

When I read *The Elements of statistical learning*, in the section of "5.5 Automatic Selection of the Smoothing Parameters", equation (5.26) gives a LOOCV formula for corresbonding $\lambda$

Here the background is fitting a smoothing spline using the data $(y_i, x_i)\ i = 1,2,...,N$. In order to select a smoothing parameter, we use LOOCV creteria.

\begin{equation}
\text{CV}(\hat{f}_{\lambda}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \hat{f}_{\lambda}^{(-i)}(x_i))^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\frac{y_i - \hat{f}_{\lambda}(x_i)}{1-S_{\lambda}(i,i)}\right)
\end{equation}

where $\hat{f}_{\lambda}^{(-i)}$ means fitting value by using model without using $(y_i, x_i)$, and $S_{\lambda}(i,i)$ is the diagonal element of the smoothing matrix $\mathbf{S}_{\lambda}$ based on whole data. ($\mathbf{S}_{\lambda} = (\mathbf{I} + \lambda \mathbf{K})^{-1} = \mathbf{N}(\mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N} + \lambda \Omega)^{-1} \mathbf{N}^T)$.

(the notation is consistent with chapter 5 in the textbook [The Elements of statistical learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/))

I wonder how to prove the second equation, so I search online and find the following post is helpful. But when I try to prove the above formula for smoothing matrix, I've run into difficulties and it's hard to carry on.

I can only prove that

\begin{equation}
(\mathbf{N}_{(t)}^T\mathbf{N}_{(t)} + \lambda \Omega)^{-1} \mathbf{N}_t^T  = (\mathbf{N}^T\mathbf{N} + \lambda \Omega)^{-1} \mathbf{N}_t^T \left(\frac{1}{1-S_{\lambda}(t,t)}\right)
\end{equation}

where the supscript $_{(t)}$ means except $t$th one, while $_t$ means the $t$th one.

Could anyone help finish the proof, or using some other method to prove the formula? I'd be grateful.

Helpful post:

@MISC {164223,
TITLE = {Proof of LOOCV formula},
AUTHOR = {Clarinetist (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/46427/clarinetist)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Cross Validated},
NOTE = {URL:[Proof of LOOCV formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164223) (version: 2015-08-04)},
EPRINT = {https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164223},
URL = {https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164223}
}

Comment: this should be related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164223/proof-of-loocv-formula/164277#164277

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know if you are still interested in this but what follows might help you in proving the results you mention in the question (...hope get everything right...it is a slippery notation ^_^).

Here I will use a bit more general notation (since the results you mention hold not only for the smoothing use case)

- We can consider a ridge regression problem $\displaystyle \min_{\beta} S(\lambda) = \| y - X \beta \|^{2} + \lambda \|\beta\|^{2}$ (if $\lambda = 0$ you will get the same results as the answer you cite).
- The LOOCV ctiretion in this case tells us to select the optimal regularization parameter as $LOOCV(\lambda) = \displaystyle \min_{\lambda} \sum_{i}^{N}(y_{i} - X_{i} \hat{\beta}_{-i} (\lambda))^{2}$
- We define $X_{i}$ as the $i$th row of the model matrix $X$
- We define as $\hat{\beta}_{-i} = (X_{-i}^{\top} X_{-i} + \lambda I)^{-1} X_{-i}^{T} y_{-i}$ the coefficients estimated when the $i$th obs is left out
- Define as $X_{-i}$ the the model matrix when the $i$th element is left out (analogous definiiton holds for $y_{-i}$)

To derive the result you are interested in we need to find an 'analytic' expression for $\hat{\beta}_{-i}$.
The proof proceeds more or less as follows (I will skip some details):

- The inverse appearing in $\hat{\beta}_{-i}$ can be shown to be equal to (this is an application of the Woodbury identity)
  $$
    (X_{-i}^{\top} X_{-i} + \lambda I)^{-1} = (X^{\top} X + \lambda I)^{-1} + (X^{\top} X + \lambda I)^{-1} X_{i}^{\top} [1-H_{ii}(\lambda)]^{-1} X_{i}(X^{\top} X + \lambda I)^{-1}
    $$
  where $H_{ii}(\lambda) = X_{i}(X^{\top} X + \lambda I)^{-1} X_{i}^{\top}$
- Plugging the result above in the equation for he LOO estimator, after some algebra, we get:
  $$
    \hat{\beta}_{-i}(\lambda) = \hat{\beta}(\lambda) - (X^{\top} X + \lambda I)^{-1} X_{i}^{\top} [1-H_{ii}(\lambda)]^{-1} (y_{i} - X_{i} \hat{\beta}(\lambda))
    $$
- Plugging the result in the equation for the LOOCV criterion, after some algebra, we can notice that
  $$
    y_{i} - X_{i} \hat{\beta}_{-i}(\lambda) = [1-H_{ii}(\lambda)]^{-1} (y_{i} - X_{i}\hat{\beta}(\lambda))
    $$
  and hence the results we are looking for follows:
  $$
    LOOCV(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(y_{i} - X_{i}\hat{\beta}(\lambda))^{2}}{(1 - H_{ii} (\lambda))^{2}}
    $$

Again, here I skip some detail (mainly tedious algebra) but these are the lines you could follow to prove the results you are interested in. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! There's only a small typo in the fomula using Woodbury identity. I think there should be a $X_i$ after $[1-H_{ii}(\lambda)]^{-1}$.

Comment: Again, there's another small typo in the last formula, I think it should be $\sum_{i=1}^{N} [1-H_{ii}(\lambda)]^{-2}(y_i - X_i\hat{\beta}(\lambda))^2$