# Usage of AIC and BIC statistics(explanation)

Tags: model-selection, aic, bic

In this post [Is there any reason to prefer the AIC or BIC over the other?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-the-aic-or-bic-over-the-other][1]) was given the answer, that

> AIC tries to select the model that most adequately describes an
>   unknown
>
> BIC tries to find the TRUE model among the set of candidates.

My question is, how can both this statistics have such different application? Their formulas are "almost" equivalent.

Comment: Neither description is accurate. They both penalize the likelihood function for over-parameterizing.  They both try to pick a model that fits well. However no model perfectly describes the data.

Comment: I think the link you provided is a duplicate and so I may elect to close the post for that reason. But at this point I have no votes left for closing.